# Backing up Firestore data incrementally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to think of the best (read automated, cheapest and easy to use) way to back up Firestore data for a production app.

I'm aware I could automate exports through a scheduled cloud function and send them over to a gcloud bucket. The problem I have with this approach is that it does not allow for "incremental updates of the new and updated documents" but only for backing up entire collections. This means that most of the data will be backed up each and every time, even though it hasn't even changed since the last backup, skyrocketing the cost up for no reason.

The approach that came to mind was having a cloud function in "my-app" project that would listen to each and every change in the Firestore, and perform the same change in the Firestore of the "my-app-backup" project.

This way, I only back up the changed data. Furthermore, backed up data would never become stale (as it's backed up in real-time), unlike the first approach where automated backups happen e.g. daily or weekly.

Is this even possible, having a single cloud function in the first Firebase project writing data into another Firebase project? If not, perhaps write the data elsewhere(not in another Firebase project)? Does the approach even make sense, or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Did you end up implementing something like this? If so, did you learn anything worth reporting? I'm about to undertake a similar task.

Comment: @GusRuss89 not yet unfortunately due to other priorities, but will definitely implement this in the following months. Did you have any other approach in mind? If you end up learning something worth sharing when implementing this feature, pls let me know here, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I haven't done anything yet but have thought a bit about it. The problem with simply replicating everything to another project is that if the 'disaster' you need to recover from is a bug that deleted or broke all your documents somehow, those deletions will be replicated. So I think you're on the right track, but you'd need to actually take backups of the main database every so often (e.g. monthly), and at the same time reset the replica database, and take backups of the replica database daily.

Comment: @GusRuss89 That was my plan, but without taking backups of replica db, as then I might as well take backups of original db. E.g. I'd run a scheduled cloud function weekly, that would go through all collections from original database, applying something alongs the lines of ` where("updatedAt", ">", "lastExportTime").` and copying that to replica db. This way I have a one week window before replica data gets overwritten and I'm good with that. One could even have a weekly and monthly replica. However, I'd much prefer if firebase offered us a way to do diff backups automatically out of the box.

Comment: @GusRuss89 However, I must say I'm tempted to forget about diff backups and use scheduled backups that backup entire db each and every time. This way, if I ever need to recover data from backup, it's trivial. I need to do some cost estimating, and if that turns out to be acceptable, I'll likely go that route

Comment: By "reset the replica" I meant reset it to empty, so it only ever contains up to a month worth of updates, which means it's much cheaper to backup every day than the entire database.

Comment: @DamjanVučina We're doing backups of the entire db. Keep in mind you'll also pay for the reads. We have 130 GB of data backed up daily which is costing ~$50 a day just for reading the data.

Comment: @Oliver Firebase recently released a new feature for firestore called PITR, haven't yet tried it out, but I think this is a game changer, and will likely opt for that instead. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pitr. This is definitely a different feature than exports, but I feel it may get the same job done in many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export updated documents only then you can store a field `updatedAt` and query documents `where("updatedAt", ">", "lastExportTime")`. Then you can periodically run a Cloud function to export these documents. This should only cost N reads (N = number of updated documents) every time the function runs.

> Furthermore, backed up data would never become stale (as it's backed up in real-time)

This works too but can also get expensive if the document updates are too frequent.

Comment: Is it possible to have that cloud function read documents from project A's Firestore and write them to project B's Firestore?

Comment: @DamjanVučina yes, you can initialize multiple instances of Firestore with Admin SDK. Then you can read from one and write to other project https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps

Comment: Great, so basically I'd have two cloud functions, instantiated with different secrets. FuncReader would be listening to changes in projectA and would upon each change call FuncWriter to mirror updates in ProjectB. 

Does this approach in general make sense to you for backup purposes?

Comment: @DamjanVučina you can do this in a single cloud function. You can initialize multiple Admin SDK instances in a single CF. Use the first one to read data and then write to another project.